# Positioning the scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

As you know, the horisontal scrolling is required it is placed on the bottom of element that is not easy to find when the bottom or element is outside of the view port. Is there any css solution (even with partial support) to change the place of vertical scrollbar?

(there is a jquery plugin for that available that create a mock element on top of overflowed element and keep its scrolling position with the scrollbar of the targeted element, it's not what I am looking for, as the created element make trouble sometimes for styling).